# Colored matt glass shade for lamp in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I'm trying to create (using Blender 2.72) a realistic model of a lamp shade (which shape can be roughly represented as a cylinder with no caps and non-zero thickness of the walls) made of a colored matt glass that would do the following (having a small sphere with a white "Emission" shader placed in the center of it):

- Attenuate the light coming through it.
- Change the color of the light coming through it.
- Reflect the light off its internal surface for the rays falling at low angles and leaving the shade through its upper/lower aperture (optional).

My current knowledge of Cycles materials (or, the lack of it) is not letting me properly "wrapping" my head around this task successfully.

Any hints on what should the graph look like are appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think all you need is a rough glass shader:

[image]

Or perhaps something like this:

[image]

Filtering out certain colors is a fairly simple matter:

[image]

Comment: Oh, that looks so easy now! I haven't tried mixing Translucent and Glass. Thanks, that does what I need! :)